# How to record a user's IP address when they sign up in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model with an "ip" attribute.  I want to save the user's IP address when they sign up in the User model.

The only problem is that it seems like when I make a method in the User model:

```
def set_ip
  self.ip = request.remote_ip
end
```

I get an error message saying "request" doesn't exist, so it doesn't look like it exists in the model.

Is there any way to set an IP address in the model or do I have to do this in the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request` is a [controller method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#method-i-request) so you can't call it from inside a model. Why not add the IP to `params` before you create your user? Something like this:

```
params[:user][:ip] = request.ip
@user = User.create(params[:user])
```

Comment: I'm new to Rails. Thanks for the answer. I was wondering if this type of code would be better in the Model to keep with MVC style?

Comment: @ethicalhack3r (1) This is preparing data for the model, that is the controller's job. (2) The model wouldn't have access to `request` anyway.

Comment: @muistooshort awesome, trying to keep to 'best practices', thanks for your answer :)